# How to filter some elements of a column in DataFrame based on the other columns value?

Tags: julia

Hi I have a DataFrame (see the screenshot) which want to filter some elemnts based on their values.

```
Announcement_data_file = "C:/Data/mini.csv"
Announcement_df = CSV.read(joinpath(Announcement_data_file), DataFrames.DataFrame)

f_ID = Announcement_df.Announcement[Announcement_df.Announcement.<100000]
s_ID = Announcement_df.Announcement[Announcement_df.Announcement.>100000]
```

The above codes work perfectly. However, the below ones give me Error. Why?

```
O_f = Announcement_df.Origin[f_ID]
```

Or, also these two

```
Announcement_df.Origin['112264']
Announcement_df.Origin[112264]
```

How can I filter `Origins` based on the valus of the Announcements??

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here are the reasons why your commands fail:

```
O_f = Announcement_df.Origin[f_ID]
```

fails, because `f_ID` is a vector `[4199, 6698]` and both these values are not in range of allowed indices of `Announcement_df.Origin` which is from 1 to 3.

```
Announcement_df.Origin['112264']
```

fails, because `'112264'` is an invalid expression in Julia. If you wanted to define a string then it should be `"112264"`, but it would be also invalid as you cannot index vectors with strings.

```
Announcement_df.Origin[112264]
```

fails, because you are trying to use `112264` index while allowed indices are from 1 to 3 as commented above.

Now, what I assume you want to do is:

```
Announcement_df.Origin[Announcement_df.Announcement .== 112264]
```